# Large temp files created in Windows Server 2003 temp folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, filesystems, encrypting-file-system

I'm managing a Windows Server 2003. A couple of times the server has crashed with error message saying that the C: drive is full. After searching folders to free up space, I found that lot of temp files being created in C:\WINNT\Temp and some of them of enormous size with more than 2GB. The temp files seem to have a common name pattern, Efs###.tmp. Since we encrypt files frequently using Windows's EFS, I initially suspected Windows encryption. But as per the documentation, Efs###.tmp are created only under [the folder which is currently](http://www.ntfs.com/issues-encrypted-files.htm) being encrypted, not in Temp folder.

This looks very strange; unless someone tried to encrypt that Temp folder itself, the temp files(Efs###.tmp) shouldn't be created under C:\WINNT\Temp. The server has Tivoli Backup client. Could that be messing with windows Encryption? Can anyone shed some light on what could be causing the issue?

Note:Edited for brewity

Comment: what backup software do you use

Comment: Tivoli storage client

Comment: ok not familiar with tivoli storage client but the storage software that I use creates a snapshot of the largest file.  It stored these in the windows\temp directory. So if you have a 4 gig file it will consume another 4 gigs just for the backup.  Not sure if this has anything to do with your issue though.

Comment: how fequently do you have the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd setup File Monitor with a suitable filter and leave it running. Or have it triggered by Performance Monitor. Certainly leave Perfmon running to see the time as this might give an indication of a cronjob running at the same time etc..

Comment: File Monitor or the PA File Sight demo -- both can tell you what app is creating those files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to unencrypt these files? You can also use the efsinfo command from the Resource kit to get more information about the files.

```
Cipher /d /a Efs###.tmp
```

Comment: Thanks...I get a message saying that the file is not encrypted when I try to decipher. But the file content is garbled